# Windsor Castle object factory "GetByName" injecting properties

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I use Castle Windsor in my c# project for DI and I've this scenario:

```
public class Class1:IMyClass
{
     public string Name{get{return "Class1";}}
     public int Version {get; set;}
     private string _description;

     public Class1(string description)
     {
        this._description=description;
     }
}
public class Class2:IMyClass
{
     public string Name{get{return "Class2";}}
     public int Version {get; set;}
     private string _description;

     public Class2(string description)
     {
        this._description=description;
     }
}
```

I can register those classes by the common IMyClass interface but now I need a factory for create a determinated instance; something like this:

```
IMyClass _myClass= someClassFactory.GetByName("Class2", version=1, description="test");
```

Is there an example for a factory that resolves a component by name and inject properties and/or constructor values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely right Cristiano. Here a bit more info.
No matter how you write your factory you will not be able to create component based on the Name property. The reason for this is that the property is only availble after creating the object, and the factory needs it before that.

Create a factory :

```
interface ISomeClassFactory 
{
    IMyClass GetById(string name, int version, string description);
}
```

and a selector  (copied from: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx)

```
public class CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if(method.Name == "GetById" && arguments.Length == 1 && arguments[0] is string)
        {
            return (string)arguments[0];
        }
        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
}
```

And register these as follows:

```
Component.For<IMyClass>().ImplementedBy<Class1>().Named("Class1"),
Component.For<IMyClass>().ImplementedBy<Class2>().Named("Class2")
Component.For<IISomeClassFactory>().AsFactory(c=> new CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector())
```

Also make sure to add the TypedFactoryFacility to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Once again [Typed factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is the solution.